# Why my sitemap.xml isn't recognized by the Google Search Console?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, xml

I have generated this `sitemap.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

  <url>
    <loc>https://maths-pour-tous.netlify.app/</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-10-09T16:34:11+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://maths-pour-tous.netlify.app/liens</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-10-09T16:34:11+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

This file is recognized to be it, but it contains errors.
In fact, it seems to appear as an HTML file according to Google Search Console.

[image: your sitemap.xml seems to be an HTML page]

Comment: Are you sure that those are the contents of the file?  How are you looking at it?  Its isnt an html rendition perhaps ?  Are you using wordpress ?  Have a look at this [Fixing “Your Sitemap Appears to Be an HTML Page” in Google Search Console](https://trustiko.com/fixing-your-sitemap-appears-to-be-html-page-google/)

Comment: I'm using reactJs, so i added this file myself in the project.

Comment: The structure and entries appear to be the same as mine.  The only line I don't  use is lastmod.  Maybe there is an error there.  I read Google doesnt care about the lastmod.  And the Browsers need it on the page header

Comment: Are you submitting the HTTPS version of the file? Are you manually uploading this file? The file that GSC is seeing does not appear to be the same file you are linking/showing above? GSC appears to be reporting there is an `<html>` tag on line 1? (This could also result from an "error" response (or redirect?) from the server.)

Comment: The file validates and looking at the response HTTP header it has the correct type of content-type: application/xml ... If this content is being generated dynamically the host that generates it may have been saturated, an error page may have a different content-type IE an HTML page ... a static sitemaps.xml is more reliable. I would also add Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml to your robots.txt file ... https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/create-robots-txt

Comment: If the error was caused by the host being saturated on a dynamically created sitemaps.xml document. A browser can not stress test the document to reproduce. But making a copy of the sitemaps.xml and posting it to the server would resolve the problem. ... simular to problems in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895030/xml-sitemap-generators-not-working

Comment: It makes no sense, but the only thing I have found is that yours seems to be the only site that returns a 200 for **domain/sitemap**.  Everything else I have tried returns a 404.  Is it possible that Google is referencing **sitemap** or **sitemap.html**.  Have you looked at the logs ?  Especially since your robots.txt does not specify a sitemap

Comment: I also found a reference to a Youtube video from John Mueller about errors with sitemap files.  Where he says that **"if you  change the name of the sitemap file, it can reset things on Google's end."**  So, give it a try.

Comment: @jozinho22, I see that you present your own error page for non-existent pages.  However, you are returning code 200.  I am not an expert, but that doesn't seem like a good strategy.  Sure, have a custom error page, I do.  But you should return 404.

Comment: I tried to change name, and add it into robots.txt.
But now Google says me : "Sitemap could not be read".
Even it is still visible at the adress

Comment: Everything appears to be returning a 404 currently? Is that expected? And this is a `text/plain` response. Something a bit peculiar... requesting `/SITEMAP.XML` and the browser appears to convert this to lowercase `/sitemap.xml` before making the request?! But this only appears to happen with "sitemap.xml", no other URL appears to be converted to lowercase?? Have you tried manually uploading the sitemap file to GSC (as I mentioned above)?

Comment: There also seems to be "something odd" with the SSL cert? Whilst the browser is accepting it just fine, attempting to use CURL (without the `-k` switch) results in an error: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". (The same with another tool I use - the request fails to connect due to HTTPS.)

Comment: the sitemap exists here (https://ma-thematique.netlify.app/sitemap.xml)

Answer (score 1):

According to John Mueller, sometimes there is a quirk with sitemap files.  And he has seen that if you change the name of the file, sometimes it can reset things at Google's end.

Since it's a video, I can't quote a snapshot here.   [The discussion starts at 52:49 mark into the video](https://youtu.be/8UBSEiO87GM?t=3169)

Try renaming it.  It doesn't has to be called sitemap

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that didn't solve the problem.
As well, I don't think I would change the file name each time I edit it...

Comment: Not each time, it was supposed to be once.