# Google Search Console not recognising sitemap or crawling the site

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap

I am having trouble getting Google to find my sitemaps, which is a problem because it can't seem to crawl the site properly either (A SPA built with Angular).

We have thousands of products listed but only 38 indexed pages.

The normal error when submitting to Google is "couldn't fetch", I've tried leaving it (for weeks) with no change.

The current status is this:
[image]
The error is "Sitemap is HTML". Note also the last read date back in September, which won't update.

I'm pretty sure the sitemap is formatted correctly: `https://example.com/en/sitemap.xml`

Using a text sitemap instead of XML makes no difference.

So why can't Google read it?
If I try again with a copy I get "couldn't fetch":
[image]

The host has said they've turned off server side caching for files with .xml extension but this made no difference.

Doing a URL inspection and then clicking test live URL seems to show that it's fine and Google can see the page ok.

I have exactly the same issue with other language versions:

`https://example.com/de/sitemap.xml`

`https://example.com/fr/sitemap.xml`

Could it be caused by the structure of the site?
The landing page at `https://example.com` simply redirects to the real site located in a subdirectory at `https://example.com/en` (or de/fr) based on browser language. Can Google handle that?

---

Edit to highlight why this isn't a duplicate of [Why my sitemap.xml isn't recognized by the Google Search Console?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140605)

That question is only part of this one (XML seen as HTML).
I have 1 file with that error, mostly it's Google unable to fetch the sitemap file at all. There is also the crawling issue.
I have seen several similar questions that do not fit this case, and have never found a useful answer. "Wait" or "change the filename" have not helped here.

Comment: This question is unfortunately off-topic for a couple of reasons: 1.) You're asking [multiple questions in one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), with the first one already asked in the question marked as a [duplicate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). 2.) We don't trouble-shoot individual sites here -- see:  [Only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: For "Couldn't Fetch" part, did you run the [Live Test in the URL Inspection tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451001?hl=en#zippy=%2Csubmit-a-sitemap) as Google suggests? When I try to request `/sitemap_en.xml` I'm receiving a `404` error. Perhaps you meant to fetch it from a subdirectory (i.e., `/en/`)? Google recommends posting a sitemap [at the site root, which can affect all files on the site](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap). Also, you shouldn't redirect sitemaps.

Comment: I'd recommend spending some time reviewing the above links, and their guide for [localized versions of Sitemaps](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions). Unfortunately we can't be of further help since there's too many issues here.

Comment: @dan Noted! Thank you for taking the time and for your feedback/advice